# Can I render some vertices as an object instead?

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0, terrain-rendering

I am generating vertices at runtime that represent terrain.

I've always drawn the vertices as triangles with `GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>`, but I'm wondering: Can vertices be converted into a "Model" so I could handle model and terrain rendering in a unified way?

[This page](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/generated_geometry) is quite similar to what I am searching for.

I want to later port my game to Mono. Would this approach cause problems when using the Content Pipeline to convert the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official answer from Shawn Hargreaves (one of the developers of XNA) is

> The XNA Model class doesn't do any optimization at runtime: that all
>   happens at build time inside the ModelProcessor. This is exactly why
>   it is impossible to create a Model instance at runtime: the Model
>   class depends on the processor to have optimized its data ready for
>   rendering. If you are generating your data procedurally at runtime,
>   there is no place for those optimizations to happen, so you're as well
>   off just using your own standalone class.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd49df6b-21b1-48a5-89ef-77d22cba2e1a/how-to-procedurally-generate-models-at-runtime?forum=xnagamestudioexpress

I do not believe this behaviour has changed. But of course you can create a wrapper class yourselves so that you can handle a series of vertices and Models in a unified way.